# Why doesn't this wildcard work the way I expect?

Tags: ls

On my user folder, I have folders like **D** ropbox, **D** ocuments, **D** ownloads & **d** ump.

`ls a*` should list all the files whose name starts with `a`. Right?
But when I gives the command `ls d*`, instead of just displaying `dump` it shows me the ls of dump directory. And When I gives the command as `ls D*`,  then it displays ls of all foldes starting with **D**

So what part did I miss in understand it?

**Edit:** Attaching a screenshot
[image: ls screenshot]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to bash man page:

> bash scans each word for the
>   characters *, ?, and [. If one of
>   these characters appears, then the
>   word is regarded as a pattern, and
>   replaced with an alphabetically sorted
>   list of file names matching the
>   pattern

and from info node for **ls**

> The `ls' program lists information
>   about files (of any type, including
>   directories).  Options and file
>   arguments can be intermixed
>   arbitrarily, as usual.
>
> For non-option command-line
>   arguments that are directories, by
>   default 'ls' lists the contents of
>   directories, not recursively, and
>   omitting files with names beginning
>   with '.'.  For other non-option
>   arguments, by default `ls' lists just
>   the file name.  If no non-option
>   arguments are specified, 'ls' lists
>   the contents of the current directory.

so when yo give `ls d*`, **d*** is expanded to sorted list of all file/directory names starting with d. So you command becomes

```
ls dump
```

and as dump is a directory name so you get the listing of all files in the directory "dump'
but when you give `ls D*`, **D*** is expanded to "**Desktop Documents Downloads Dropbox**", so the command becomes

```
ls Desktop Documents Downloads Dropbox
```

and as all of these are directories, you get the listing of files in individual directory. If there was a file starting with **D** in current directory it would have been listed seperately.

Comment: A minor addition: When more than one directory is given as an argument, ls displays the name of each directory before listing its content. It will not do it for a single directory.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared my doubt. I did a `ls p*` and it showed up a file because it exists and a `ls P*` shows the _Pictures Public_ folder as there is no file starting with **P**. And when I created a directory named **poo**, it showed up on `ls p*`

Answer (score 7):

ls d* and D* both list files and folders matching d* and D* respectively, the behaviour is the same, there must have been a mistake on your test.

If you want to list only the folder names and not the folder contents you need to use "-d":

```
ls -d D*
```

Comment: I have attached a screenshot, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, `-d` option is way to go.  Adding

```
alias ld='ls -d'
```

to my `~/.bashrc` file works well for me.

Comment: With this alias, you block easy access to `ld - The GNU linker`, which will keep the OP from compiling and linking programs. Use `alias lsd='ls -d'` instead. Before aliasing something as `foo` always do `type foo` to see if `foo` is already used as the name for something, and decide if the convenience of the alias override the loss of access to the previous `foo`